# Environ Function code samples for VBA

Tags: vba, environment-variables

I am looking for some information or code samples for the `Environ` Function in VBA to grab the username on the current system.

Comment: @the_drow: I ask that every day I press alt+f11.  I blame Spolsky.

Comment: Gentlemen, I am looking to do 2 things; identify what my user name is on my PC (using the Environ Function) and once i understand that, I would like to write a statement that closes my database if the user is not me (in other words, if opened on another PC) Can you help me get started?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`Environ()` gets you the value of any environment variable.  These can be found by doing the following command in the Command Prompt:

```
set
```

If you wanted to get the username, you would do:

```
Environ("username")
```

If you wanted to get the fully qualified name, you would do:

```
Environ("userdomain") & "\" & Environ("username")
```

#### References

- Microsoft | Office VBA Reference | Language Reference VBA | [Environ Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/environ-function)
- Microsoft |  Office Support | [Environ Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Environ-Function-53940256-e91a-4163-b9ac-79b1dd85e4a5)

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for, just a little help getting started, thank you.

Comment: Don't forget that Environ is one of the functions blocked in Sandbox mode: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HP010447361033.aspx

Comment: Also, don't forget that Environ is a cached copy of what the environment variable was when the parent process started. Found this out the hard way.

Comment: Gentlemen, I am looking to do 2 things; identify what my user name is on my PC (using the Environ Function) and once i understand that, I would like to write a statement that closes my database if the user is not me (in other words, if opened on another PC) Can you help me get started? –  Marchese Il Chihuahua 4 secs ago   edit

Answer (score 24):

As alluded to by Eric, you can use environ with ComputerName argument like so:

```
MsgBox Environ("USERNAME")
```

Some additional information that might be helpful for you to know:

1. The arguments are *not* case sensitive.
2. There is a slightly faster performing string version of the Environ function. To invoke it, use a dollar sign. (Ex: Environ$("username")) This will net you a small performance gain.
3. You can retrieve all System Environment Variables using this function. (Not just username.) A common use is to get the "ComputerName" value to see which computer the user is logging onto from.
4. I don't recommend it for most situations, but it can be occasionally useful to know that you can also access the variables with an *index*. If you use this syntax the the name of argument *and* the value are returned. In this way you can enumerate all available variables. Valid values are 1 - 255.

```
    Sub EnumSEVars()
        Dim strVar As String
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To 255
            strVar = Environ$(i)
            If LenB(strVar) = 0& Then Exit For
            Debug.Print strVar
        Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Some time when we use `Environ()` function we may get the Library or property not found error.  Use `VBA.Environ()` or `VBA.Environ$()` to avoid the error.