# How do I make an Access Form automatically open to a user's data?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to write VB code that would allow Access to recognize the computer ID of the person opening the database, open a form, and filter to the records assigned to the user.  Does anyone know how to accomplish that?

Comment: what you're asking for is certainly possible, but you probably won't get a complete answer to your question in on giant question.  Why don't you try splitting your project into smaller questions?  For example, your first question might be: "How can I write VBA code in Access to identify the Computer being used when a person opens a database?"  Breaking your question into smaller chunks will help you get better answers to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

An [API to get the user name](http://www.mvps.org/access/api/api0008.htm) is probably better than using [Environ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935160/environ-for-vba). If the name is available in a table, you can use [DLookUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa159044(v=office.10).aspx) to get an ID, which can be used with [the Where argument of the OpenForm method of the DoCmd object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238021(office.12).aspx) to open a filtered list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Environ$("ComputerName") if that is what you mean by ComputerID. Here's a quick and dirty way I did it.  Note that the user can usually turn off the form's filter.
As others have stated, the environment variables on the PC have the potential to be modified by a non-admin user.

If you're concerned that the user will modify the environment variable for computer (i.e., SET COMPUTERNAME=MYBOSS via cmd) you can use a Win32 API call to get the ComputerName value if you know that the user is a non-admin user who cannot modify the computername via registry or through windows (see below).

**CAVEAT with API**

If the user has Admin privilege on the PC and they are able to edit the HKLM registry  values then they could make the following registry entry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName]
"ComputerName"="MyBossComputerName"
```

If they restart the PC the Windows API call will use the incorrect name.  They could then set the registry entry back to normal and restart PC.

In my scenario I have multiple users working on different days from same PC and Access Database.  They open the database from a shared folder location on the PC.  When they click the switchboard item and the form opens up the form's Load event runs.  This form is bound to a table with a column named USERNAME which is simply the environment variable value of UserName (ex. John.Smith).

Here's the VBA I put in the load event:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim currUser As String
    DoCmd.Maximize
    currUser = Environ$("USERNAME")
    Me.Filter = "USERNAME = '" & currUser & "'"
    Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

**API Call Solution**

If you'd prefer to make an API call to get the ComputerName instead then you can do the following:

The API call is GetComputerName is a derivation from code either from Ken Getz (VBA Developer's Handbook) or Dan Appleman (Visual Basic Programmer's Guide to the Win32 API).
You'll also find it all over the internet.  First add a Module to your project rename it
API or something meaningful.  Then insert the following code:

```
Private Declare Function GetComputerName Lib "kernel32" _ 
   Alias "GetComputerNameA"(ByVal strBuffer As String, lngSize As Long) As Long

Public Function ComputerNameValue() As String
   Dim strBuffer as String
   Dim retValApi as Long
   Dim bufferSize as Long

   bufferSize = 256

   strBuffer = Space(bufferSize)

   'bufferSize will be returned with ComputerName length less null character.'

   retValApi = GetComputerName(strBuffer, bufferSize) 

   If CBool(retValApi) Then
      ComputerNameValue = Left$(strBuffer, bufferSize)
   Else
     'Your Error Handler'
   End If

End Function
```

In the form load event (modified to use API wrapper function instead of Envrion$):

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim PCName As String
    DoCmd.Maximize
    PCName = ComputerNameValue()
    Me.Filter = "COMPUTERNAME = '" & PCName & "'"
    Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `Environ$("ComputerName")` is really not a good idea. I can easily pretend to be using my boss's computer by opening a command prompt, typing `SET ComputerName=MyBossComputer` then running Access from the same command prompt. The only reliable way to get the computer name is via the Windows APIs referenced in @Remou's answer.

Comment: I agree with the statement partially, I'll revise the code snippet. If the workplace doesn't have the PCs locked down and/or a user has Admin rights with the ability to modify the HKLM hive then they could easily make a registry entry: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName] "ComputerName"="MyBossComputer"  Restart OS. Open up the Access Form. When the code makes the API Call to Kernel32::GetComputerNameA it will have read this registry entry at startup. So the API is reliable as long as the user cannot modify the HKLM hive on the PC.

Comment: That edit changes the name of the local computer, and if it's on the same LAN as the computer of the same name, it would cause certain kinds of namespace collisions (depending on how name resolution is done -- in the likely scenario with admin permission for the user, it would be peer-to-peer, in which case resolution is likely by NETBios broadcast, which would lead to an error). But, point taken.