# 2003 MS Access Visual Basic Workflow

Tags: vba, ms-access, workflow

Does anyone know how to program a database to function as a workflow? I would like it to identify the user as they open the database and then open up their 'queue' of work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read Remou's answer to this Stack Overflow question: [How do I make an Access Form automatically open to a user's data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195888/how-do-i-make-an-access-form-automatically-open-to-a-users-data/4197964#4197964)

It may help to describe your concept of a user's queue of work.