# How to take filename as input as create a file in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim ts As Scripting.TextStream
Dim c As Range

Dim filename As Variant
Dim colcount As Integer
colcount = 2
Worksheets("ShipmentTracker(AL3)").Activate
filename = InputBox("Enter File Name", "file name", Worksheets("ShipmentTracker(AL3)").Cells(3, 2).Value)
Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\soora\Desktop\Meng Project\Shipment Tracker" & filename, ForAppending, True)
For Each c In Range("A9", Range("A9").End(xlDown))
    For i = 1 To colcount
        ts.Write c.Offset(0, i - 1).Value
        If i < colcount Then ts.Write vbTab

    Next i
    ts.WriteLine
Next c
ts.Close
Set fso = Nothing
```

I am taking **`filename`** as input and using that to create a new file into which I want to write data. But this does not work.

I want to create files with user input **`filename`** and write data to it.

Comment: Why it doesn't work? one thing that is obvious to me you didn't put "\" between directory and file name.

Comment: Additionally, ensure user's input filename has an extension or include it your code: `.xlsx, .txt, .csv`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Environ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935160/environ-function-code-samples-for-vba)

```
Option Explicit
Sub TEST()
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim ts As Scripting.TextStream
    Dim c As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim filename As Variant
    Dim colcount As Integer
    Dim sPath As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '// SaveAs Path
    sPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\Meng Project\Shipment Tracker\"

    colcount = 2

    Worksheets("ShipmentTracker(AL3)").Activate
    filename = InputBox("Enter File Name", "file name", _
                Worksheets("ShipmentTracker(AL3)").Cells(3, 2).Value)

    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(sPath & filename, ForAppending, True)

    For Each c In Range("A9", Range("A9").End(xlDown))
        For I = 1 To colcount
            ts.Write c.Offset(0, I - 1).Value
            If I < colcount Then ts.Write vbTab
        Next I
        ts.WriteLine
    Next c

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ts.Close
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

[MSDN Environ Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264486.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)