# How to open windows folder without using username via vba?

Tags: excel, vba, shell, download

I am trying to open a windows folder (Downloads folder) via a commandbutton in a userform in Excel. However I want to use a generic folder path to access the downloads folder so whoever has this excel file can open their downloads folder.
I got this code from the internet but it doesn't work, it only opens the document folder which I believe is the default folder.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Shell "explorer.exe" & " " & "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Downloads", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the `Environ()` function:

```
"C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Downloads"
```

[Environ Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935160/environ-function-code-samples-for-vba/937900)

Comment: THANK YOUUU!!! It worked, you made my day. Have a nice weekend.

Comment: This is the code I used to make it worked.                                                     
        Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
                    Shell "explorer.exe" & " " & "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & 
        "\Downloads", vbNormalFocus
            End Sub